# Add lines using contents of a list

Tags: vim

If I had a sentence - "I know a person named Ted who likes //^$" - or basically a sentence with a lot characters I didn't feel like escaping, and I wanted to insert copies of that sentence with different names (e.g. John Mary Bob)...

Can a for loop do this by copying the sentence, pasting it as the next line, and then subbing out the name? How do I tell it where to paste?

I could also paste the list of names in first and then sub the sentence in around the names - eg `:s/^/I know a person named /`, but I find that if there is a lot of text with a lot characters to escape, I'll probably make an error somewhere and waste time having to scrutinize the expression.

So then, is there an easier way to grab the contents from the sentence and put it into a substitute command?

Comment: Please, add a before/after example. As it is I have no idea what you are trying to achieve. What are those special characters at the end of the sentence? Are they always the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Chiel92 suggests, a macro is the easiest way. Suppose you have a text file that looks like this:

```
I know a person named XXX who like //^$

John
Mary
Bob
```

Personally I would:

1. Go to line 1, and copy the line into a named buffer: `:1<enter>"iyy`
2. Go to line 3 and record a macro that copies the name on the line, pastes the contents of the `i` buffer, and then replaces XXX with the name that was on the line:

   1. Go to line 3: `:3<enter>`
   2. Start recording a macro to register m: `qm`
   3. Delete the name into a different register: `"od$`
   4. Paste in the template: `"ipkdd`
   5. Replace XXX with the name: `:s/XXX/^Ro/`
   6. Go to the next line: `j`
   7. Finish recording: `q`

For each name line you can now replay the macro: `@m` or `@@`

Note: when making macros and have problems replaying I always find it helpful to look at the contents of my recording registry. You can just do `^R^Rm` to see all the commands you recorded.

Comment: I don't know why, but I never thought of using a macro for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a macro in vim.
Check here for a explanation of vim macros: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Macros.
It's a lot easier than using regex stuff.

Comment: My next was going to be how to use a macro for a large list, which I think is why I never thought to use a macro. But that link has a recursive macro trick that is pretty slick.